# OpenGL ES 1 Scaling without changing lighting on object?

Tags: ios, 3d, opengl-es-1.1

I am implementing a 3d obj viewer like app and when I did a scaling on my object in the app (in OpenGL ES 1.x) it became lighter(scale down) and darker (when I scale up).

Is there a way for me to prevent this "changing of lighting" to happen? i.e. the same brightness uniformly through out.

I guess I have to do something to the lighting normals?

My Render method is as below:

```
void RenderingEngine::Render(const vector<Visual>& visuals, ivec2 screenSize) const
{
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

vector<Visual>::const_iterator visual = visuals.begin();
for (int visualIndex = 0; visual != visuals.end(); ++visual, ++visualIndex) {

    // Set the viewport transform.
    ivec2 size = visual->ViewportSize;
    ivec2 lowerLeft = visual->LowerLeft;
    glViewport(lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y, size.x, size.y);

    // Set the light position.
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    vec4 lightPosition(0.25, 0.25, 1, 0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition.Pointer());

    // Set the model-view transform.
    mat4 rotation = visual->Orientation.ToMatrix();
    mat4 translation = visual->Translate;
    mat4 scale;
    scale = scale.Scale(visual->Scale);
    rotation = rotation * scale;
    //mat4 modelview = rotation * m_translation;
    mat4 modelview = rotation * m_translation * translation;

    glLoadMatrixf(modelview.Pointer());

    // Set the projection transform.
    float h = 4.0f * size.y / size.x;
    mat4 projection = mat4::Frustum(-2, 2, -h / 2, h / 2, 5, 50);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(projection.Pointer());

    // Set the diffuse color.
    vec3 color = visual->Color * 0.75f;
    vec4 diffuse(color.x, color.y, color.z, 1);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse.Pointer());

    // Draw the surface.
    int stride = 2 * sizeof(vec3);
    const GLvoid* normalOffset = (const GLvoid*) sizeof(vec3);
    const Drawable& drawable = m_drawables[visualIndex];
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, drawable.VertexBuffer);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride, 0);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, stride, normalOffset);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, drawable.IndexBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, drawable.IndexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me. So I'll be sharing this for any newbies to the subject who run into the same problem as me.

Use:

```
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
```

to always normalize the surface normals to unit length.

Answer (score 0):

First off, apply your rotation and scale matrices BEFORE your tranlation matrix(or matrices).  So... instead of this:

```
rotation = rotation * scale;
//mat4 modelview = rotation * m_translation;
mat4 modelview = rotation * m_translation * translation;
```

Do this:

```
rotation = rotation * scale;
//mat4 modelview = rotation * m_translation;
mat4 modelview = m_translation * translation * rotation;
```

Secondly, why do you have two translation matrices? You should just need one matrix to transition your object vertices from object space into world space.

Third, why are you creating a normal matrix? Unless you are modifying normals for some sheared object post rotate, I don't really see any reason to do so. You can rotate the normals for your object using the same rotation matrix you use for your vertices.

Comment: Regarding your last question, I am truly sorry! As I have both implementation of ES1.x and ES2.x for device compatibility, I had accidentally attached the codes from my ES2.x render method instead of the ES1.x codes which I intended to. I had made the necessary editing to the question.

Comment: Firstly the reason why I placed the rotation matrix after the translation is because my app is something similar to a 3d obj viewer. where i load a .obj file and view it with some multi-touch gestures.
I apologize as I did not mention this earlier.

Comment: Secondly, as it is a 3d obj viewer, I did a translation to bring the object 'behind' the screen i.e. m_translation and following which, during app run time, I will translate the model using 'translation' from user input hence the two different translation matrixes.

Comment: Oh, ok that makes much more sense. Are you applying a translation matrix to your normals? Because they should only be multiplied by a rotation matrix.

Comment: I did not apply any transformation directly to the normals, but I can't be too sure if I did so indirectly.. as I am still pretty new to the subject. 

Anyway, I had just found a solution to the problem. I enable the opengl function to normalize the normals to unit length. Although it might incur some performance hit at least it solved the issue on hand. Thanks for your time and responses!